# A function to delete a bidirectional cyclic linked list doesn't have the desired effect

Tags: c++

```
struct Node
{
    int val;
    Node* leftnode;
    Node* rightnode;
};
void createlist(Node** head)
{
    Node *p, *tail;
    int value, length = n;
    *head = new Node;
    (*head)->rightnode = NULL;
    (*head)->leftnode = NULL;
    tail = *head;
    while (length--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &value);
        p = new Node;
        p->val = value;
        p->leftnode = tail;
        tail->rightnode = p;
        tail = p;
    }
    Node* first = (*head)->rightnode;
    tail->rightnode = first;
    first->leftnode = tail;
    delete *head; 
    *head = first;
}
```

This is the way I define a function to create a bidirectional circular list.
And here's the function to delete it.

```
void deletelist(Node* head, int n)
{
    Node* first = head;
    head = head->rightnode;
    while (head != first)
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        head = head->rightnode;
        delete temp;
    }
    delete head;
}
```

My g++ version

```
g++ (x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I have checked the code. It seems that only `delete head;` get what I expected and `delete cur;` make no effect. If I change the code to

```
void deletelist(Node** head, int n)
{
    Node* first = head;
    head = head->rightnode;
    while (head != first)
    {
        Node** temp = &head;
        head = head->rightnode;
        delete *temp;
    }
    delete head;
}
```

It got what I wanted.

The old whole code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int val;
    Node* leftnode;
    Node* rightnode;
};
void createlist(Node** head);
void showvalue2(Node* head, int n);
void deletelist(Node* head, int n);
int n;
int main()
{

    cin >> n;
    Node* head;
    createlist(&head);
    showvalue2(head, n);
    deletelist(head, n);
    showvalue2(head, n);
}
void createlist(Node** head)
{
    Node *p, *tail;
    int value, length = n;
    *head = new Node;
    (*head)->rightnode = NULL;
    (*head)->leftnode = NULL;
    tail = *head;
    while (length--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &value);
        p = new Node;
        p->val = value;
        p->leftnode = tail;
        tail->rightnode = p;
        tail = p;
    }
    Node* first = (*head)->rightnode;
    tail->rightnode = first;
    first->leftnode = tail;
    delete *head; 
    *head = first;
}
void showvalue2(Node* p, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << p->val << " " << p << endl;
        p = p->rightnode;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void deletelist(Node* head, int n)
{
    Node* first = head;
    head = head->rightnode;
    while (head != first)
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        head = head->rightnode;
        delete temp;
    }
    delete head;
}
```

I input

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

just got

```
1 0x721620
2 0x721640
3 0x721660
4 0x721680
5 0x7216a0

1 0x721620
40180880 0x721640
3 0x721660
4 0x721680
5 0x7216a0
```

We can see it just delete the second Node.
May anyone give me an reasonable explanation?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] which we can compile ad run. You can [use this site](https://godbolt.org/z/zvTd3Gzqd) to provide nice demo of the problem.

Comment: I tried to debug, but the outcome showed me that the address of temp and head is correct to delete the list. Maybe there're some faults in my knowledge of memory management. so sad...

Comment: Also I would recommend to change API design. `void PushToFrontOfList(Node** head, int value)`. So IO operation is separated from list logic.

Comment: sorry, I'm still a freshman and start learning list... Your advice is helpful

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional details. Code in comments is unreadable.